# Reinstall on Proscan PLT7650G Tablet?

Tags: applications, rooting, installation, tablet

My son has a Proscan PLT7650G tablet that will not get past the ProScan startup logo.  I have tried a factory reset and its still a no go.  Before I throw in the towel I want to try an OS reinstall but I am not sure how to go about it.  I am a programmer/dba/sys admin and I am not afraid to take it on but my knowledge of Android is very limited.

Comment: Can you tell on which plateform is that tablet: Spreadtrum, Mediatek or AllWinner? I didn't find anything about that

Comment: I honestly do not know, how would I check?

Comment: Does this help?  https://www.amazon.com/Proscan-7-Inch-Screen-Android-Tablet/dp/B018YGD846/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1494015630&sr=8-2&keywords=proscan+plt7650g#productDetails

Comment: Unfortunately no, they don't say which processor (chipset) the device has inside...

Comment: I found this link, but can't go further as the site is restricted for my region: http://www.proscanvideo.com/manuals-downloads?category_group=456&category=457

Comment: According to this link it says it has a Rockchip 3126 Cortex-A7 Quad-Core 1.2GHz processor

https://www.rakuten.com/prod/proscan-plt7650g-r-7-quadcore-1-2ghz-8gb-android-5-1-wifi-tablet-w/297542329.html

Comment: Okay, You need LiveSuiteEn to be able to flash a RockShip

Comment: Here is a video of it in action...

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxJjaCFuo-5Ldmw0eDRvS2U0aHc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Yeah, the hard part is finding the firmware. I've been searching but with no success so far

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- Download the firmware from this [site](http://www.proscanvideo.com/)
- Extract downloaded .zip (Should contain a .img file)
- Rename .img file to update.img (If it isn't already)
- Copy update.img onto SD card (Should be the only thing on the card)
- Reboot. Should install the file.

You should read more [here](http://%20Extract%20downloaded%20.zip%20(Should%20contain%20a%20.img%20file)%203.%20Rename%20.img%20file%20to%20update.img%20(If%20it%20isn't%20already)%204.%20Connect%20tablet%20to%20your%20computer%20via%20USB%20and%20format%20the%20SD%20card%20(Make%20sure%20it%20is%20not%20the%20internal%20storage!!!)%205.%20Copy%20update.img%20onto%20SD%20card%20(Should%20be%20the%20only%20thing%20on%20the%20card)%206.%20Eject%20tablet%20from%20computer%20(Should%20be%20two%20mount%20points)%20and%20turn%20off%20%22USB%20Mass%20Storage%22%20on%20tablet.)

Comment: Not sure if the link was removed etc but I could not find the firmware on the proscan website.

Answer (score 0):

So I have searched and search for the firmware for this old tablet and I have found it decided to go ahead and release it for the public in case of people stuck with a bricked tablet.Everything you need to get this tablet back up and running is in the zip file. If you have any issues feel free to hit me up anytime!

LINK TO FIRMWARE:

https://mega.nz/#F!w35iWAqZ!TKWNZs-lLFbguaEog5bIWg